# SQL Query to show data in the form of Matrix

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I'm using the following SQL query to fetch the records.

***I want to achieve the top 10 most flown origins and destination and their count respectively.***

```sql
SELECT TOP 10 dep.ICAO 'Origin', arr.ICAO 'Destination', COUNT(dep.Id) AS Total
FROM TripSectors ts
JOIN Airports dep ON ts.DepartureAirportId = dep.Id
LEFT JOIN Airports arr on arr.Id = ts.ArrivalAirportId
WHERE ts.ArrivalAirportId IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY dep.ICAO, arr.ICAO
ORDER BY Total  DESC
```

**RESULT**

```sql
Origin  Destination Total
KHND    KSDL    8541
KSNA    KHND    8359
KHND    KPSP    8275
KPSP    KHND    8267
KHND    KCRQ    8266
KCNO    KHND    8250
KHND    KCNO    8237
KHND    KTUS    8237
KHND    KAPC    8215
KCVO    KHND    8183
```

**I need my data in this form like MATRIX** because of origin and destination total is kept changing. I want something like dynamic headers for the destination.

```sql
Origin  KSDL    KPSP    KCRQ    KCNO    KTUS   KAPC
KHND    8541    8275    8266    8237    8237   8215
```

**I tried this but not getting required result**

```sql
DECLARE @SQLQUERY  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @PivotColumns AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT distinct top 10 @PivotColumns = COALESCE(@PivotColumns + ',', '') + QUOTENAME(arr.ICAO)
FROM TripSectors ts
JOIN Airports arr on arr.Id = ts.ArrivalAirportId
WHERE ts.ArrivalAirportId IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY arr.ICAO

--SELECT @PivotColumns

SET @SQLQUERY = N'WITH Locations AS (
   SELECT
      d.ICAO As Origin,
      d.Id AS OriginId
   FROM
      dbo.TripSectors S
      INNER JOIN dbo.Airports d ON S.DepartureAirportId = d.Id)

SELECT *, '+ @PivotColumns +'
FROM Locations
PIVOT (Count(OriginId) FOR Origin IN ('+ @PivotColumns +')) P
';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQUERY
```

Comment: you need `PIVOT` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I've tried with ```PIVOT``` but no luck :(

Comment: Show the query you used with the `PIVOT`.

Comment: Are you after 3 different datasets as well..?

Comment: @Larnu I have only 1 dataset

Comment: In your expected Matrix you have 3 datasets, not 1.

Comment: @Larnu I have 1 dataset but my expectation is like the top 10 or more datasets in return.

Comment: You have new column headings in your later rows, @awais. You can't have multiple column heading in a single data set. That is 3 datasets.

Comment: We also still need that attempt you made with `PIVOT`, please. It's impossible for us to tell you why that query isn't working, when we don't know what that query was.

Comment: @Larnu multiple column headings are dynamic as mentioned in a result set and also my expectations in a matrix form. Origin and destinations are changing as per ```COUNT(dep.Id) AS Total```

Comment: That isn't how a SQL dataset work, @awais . You can't have headings further down the rowset. The headers are separate to the rowset data. If you want different headings, you need multiple datasets. What you are showing us there are 3 distinct datasets.

Comment: Attempts go in the question please, not the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your require `Resultset` in `#temp` table.
`Dynamic Sql` should be as short as possible.It is easy to debug.

```
create table #temp(Origin varchar(30),Destination varchar(30), Total int)
insert into #temp
values
 ('KHND','KSDL',8541)
,('KSNA','KHND',8359)
,('KHND','KPSP',8275)
,('KPSP','KHND',8267)
,('KHND','KCRQ',8266)
,('KCNO','KHND',8250)
,('KHND','KCNO',8237)
,('KHND','KTUS',8237)
,('KHND','KAPC',8215)
,('KCVO','KHND',8183)

declare @PvtCol varchar(500)=''

declare @Sql nvarchar(500);

--select * from #temp

;With CTE as
(
select  Destination,total
,row_number()over(partition by Destination  order by total desc)rn 
from #temp

)
SELECT 
@PvtCol = COALESCE(@PvtCol + ', ' + QUOTENAME(Destination), QUOTENAME(Destination))   
FROM cte
where rn=1
--and Destination<>'KHND'
order by total desc


SET @PvtCol = STUFF(@PvtCol, 1, 1, '');

SELECT @PvtCol;


set @Sql='select Origin,'+@PvtCol+' from
       (select Origin,Destination,Total from #temp /*where origin=''KHND''*/) as src
       pivot(max(total) for Destination in( '+@PvtCol+')) as pvt';

print @Sql
execute sp_executesql @Sql


drop table #temp
```

if you are looking for only individual origin then you can uncomment `where origin=''KHND'' and --and Destination<>'KHND'`

Comment: Thank you @KumarHarsh you're a Rockstar.